# Check if two selects are "selected" (JQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey I have a little problem with my jquery application. I have two select-Elements. I want to make a backend call, when the user selected a value from these two select-Elements. For this I created two boolean variables:

`var fromAirportActivated = false;`
`var toAirportActivated = false;`

When the user selects something, these variables should change to "true".

```
$('#fromAirport').on('change', function () {
    fromAirportActivated == true;
});

$('#toAirport').on('change', function () {
    toAirportActivated == true;
});
```

If both of them changed, I want to make a call to the backend. I check this with a if-loop.

```
if (fromAirportActivated == true && toAirportActivated == true) {
    console.log('working!');
    //Here I would make the backend call
}
```

The problem is, that i do not get a log in my console and i do not really know why. Has anyone of you ideas?

Comment: `fromAirportActivated == true;` should be `fromAirportActivated = true;` `=` is assignment, `==` is comparison

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll` and add event listener Inside the listener call back check the id of the `select` element and accordingly update the variable. Now on every change check for the variable state and if both are true then make an api call

```js
let fromAirportActivated, toAirportActivated;
// let all relevant selects have a same class  by name selects
// then select the select dom and add event listener to them 
const sels = document.querySelectorAll('.selects').forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    // check if current select have this id
    if (e.target.id === 'fromAirport') {
      fromAirportActivated = true;
    }
    if (e.target.id === 'toAirport') {
      toAirportActivated = true;
    }
    // if both are true then make call
    if (toAirportActivated && fromAirportActivated) {
      console.log('Make API call now')
    }

  })

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class='selects' id='fromAirport'>
  <option value='1'>1</option>
  <option value='2'>2</option>
  <option value='3'>3</option>
</select>

<select id='toAirport' class='selects'>
  <option value='1'>1</option>
  <option value='2'>2</option>
  <option value='3'>3</option>

</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing value instead of assigning when onchange event occurs. Do:

```
$('#fromAirport').on('change', function () {
    fromAirportActivated = true;
});

$('#toAirport').on('change', function () {
    toAirportActivated = true;
});
```